# count the number of occurrences of all word in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file like below:

```
abc
mnm
xyz
abc
abc
xyz
```

Now I want to know the count of each word in the file with a single command in UNIX. Is that possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it takes two programs but it's just one statement:

```
sort filename.txt | uniq -c
```

You could also write a shell function:

```
counts() {
     sort "$@" | uniq -c
}
```

Then you can simply say:

```
counts filename.txt
```

Comment: Great.. Thanks a lot